# Echoprint iOS Missing Framework

Tags: ios, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

Has anyone downloaded the demo iOS version of EchoPrint?  It's an audio fingerprinting open source software.

I just downloaded it but it appears to missing framework... any place to get a functioning version?

Comment: have you configured EchoPrint.. or still stuck up

Comment: Hi @VimalVenugopalan: have u done any demo application Echoprint framework...Am facing some linkage issues and Av foundation issues when i run app..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Follow the steps to get it the framework running

1. Download latest version of [boost](http://www.boost.org/) . The download [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.51.0/boost_1_51_0.tar.gz/download) for latest 1.51.0 for boost library
2. Extract the **boost_1_51_0.tar.gz** file.
3. Download the project for generation of **libechoprint-codegen-ios.a** famework from [here](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-codegen/)
4. Open the project and set the Header Search Path as the path of the extracted boost folder. e.g. in my case the below is the path

   > **/Users/$(USER)/Downloads/boost_1_51_0/boost_1_51_0**
   >   [image: Screenshot1]
5. Open the **echoprint-codegen-ios.xcconfig** file and add the same path in the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
   [image: Screenshot2]
6. Now clean and build the project would give you  **libechoprint-codegen-ios.a** under Products folder
7. Now download the [Echoprint iOS Sample](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-ios-sample)
8. Building this project would give you Errors as the files of **ASIHTTP** folder and the **libechoprint-codegen-ios.a** framework is missing are not added to the xcode project but are physically present in the project Folder.[image: Screenshot3]
9. Delete this folder from the project and drag-drop the **physical folder** to the **xcode project**. Also delete and add only the **libechoprint-codegen-ios.a** framework to this project from the previously compiled project.
10. Now you are ready with an error-free code.

Comment: If my effort helped in solving your issue.. please approve it.

Comment: @VimalVenugopalan - Hi this works for the echoprint ios sample, but when I add the libechoprint-codegen-ios.a from my project I get bullet linker errors. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: See my repo below for XCode 5 implementation

Answer (score 3):

Update for people who are still interested in this and are using XCode 5 + iOS 7 + LLVM 5.0.

I have forked the sample repo, upgraded it to XCode 5+ iOS 7 and modified it to automatically build in the echoprint-codegen dependency as a sub-project: https://github.com/rexstjohn/echoprint-ios-sample.

The above instructions will no longer work for the latest XCode + iOS.

Comment: Do you have to link to the boost/boost folder or just /boost? I get errors on both :( [inker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)] or [

Comment: hi @Delete: am getting boost/boost errors and linkage error while running the app

Comment: Just google "download boost 1.5+" and download the libraries.