# Echoprint implementation

Tags: c++, ios, c, codegen

I'm implementing echoprint in my iOS 6 app but when I compile my project it gives me errors from Codegen.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "Codegen::Codegen(float const*, unsigned int, int)", referenced from:
      codegen_wrapper(float const*, int) in Codegen_wrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

How to compile and run Codegen on iOS is explained here:

[Echoprint iOS Missing Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135898/echoprint-ios-missing-framework)

Since simulator in XCode uses i386 processor, it fails to link it with object which is compiled in arm7.

While compiling `libechoprint-codegen-ios.a` choose `iPhone Simulator` as target, then you will have it compiled in i386. Then it will successfully link it. You can learn whether it is compiled in arm7 or i386 by typing

`lipo -info path/libechoprint-codegen-ios.a`

source: http://www.verious.com/qa/linker-error-for-echoprint-in-ios/