# Linker error for echoprint in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

I'm using echoprint API for song search from last 3 months. But suddenly it started giving me below errors. Already I have face many problems while adding that API to my project & now it start giving me linker error. It was working for me previously.
Error like this:

> "Codegen::Codegen(float const*, unsigned int, int)", referenced from: _GetPCMFromFile in File.o
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/prajaktakulkarni/Downloads/echoprint-codegen-4.12 2/src/echoprint-codegen-ios/build/Release-iphoneos'
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/prajaktakulkarni/Documents/Instajam/libechoprint-codegen-ios.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/prajaktakulkarni/Documents/Instajam/libechoprint-codegen-ios.a (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "Codegen::Codegen(float const*, unsigned int, int)", referenced from:
>         _GetPCMFromFile in File.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run it on the simulator. Does it work if you run it on a device?

Comment: Oh!!!! Thanks James for remembering the thing.... It work for me now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that the static library libechoprint-codegen-ios.a hasn't been built for the i386 architecture - which is the architecture used by the simulator.

You can find out which architectures the static library has been built for by running the following code in Terminal:

```
lipo -info ~/Documents/Instajam/libechoprint-codegen-ios.a
```

It will likely tell you it is built for armv7 and armv7s.  That will support all but the oldest iOS devices at the time of writing.

You could build libechoprint-codegen-ios.a to run on a simulator.  Here's a good stackoverflow post if you are interested in doing that: [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)

The easiest option would be to just plug your phone in and not worry about building a fat static library. :D

Comment: After struggling with the static library, I ended up paying the 99$ to Apple to run on my iPod Touch, now when I try to run it I get `The identity 'iPhone Developer: Brian Whitman (XXXXXXXXX)' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains`. This Brian guy is the Co-Founder of ECHOnest or something similar.... anything I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @AvielGross you should follow the steps here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html

Comment: thanks it helped, now i'm stuck with some other error when tryin to build: `CodeSign error: The entitlements file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Entitlements.plist' is missing` and after that: `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Recently the problem was fixed for me by using **libz.1.1.3.tbd** instead **libz.tbd** and of course this link is useful [Echoprint iOS Missing Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135898/echoprint-ios-missing-framework)